# android unparseble date Exception?

Tags: java, android, date

I am making an application in which i am using date functionality,but looking after several existing posts, I am still not able to get my `SimpleDateFormat` parser working.

Here is the code:

```
public class GPSDemo extends Activity {

public static String TAG = "Abhi's Log";

public static String IMEII = "imei";
public static String START_TIME = "startTime";
public static String WORKING_STATUS = "workingStatus";
public static String ADDRESS = "address";
public static int level = 0;

Button stop, hide;

SharedPreferences pref;
Editor edit;

Date d1 = null;
Date d2 = null;

String startingTime;
String currentTime;

Context ctx = this;

TextView txt_start_time, txt_total_time, txt_total_distance, txt_address;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.demoooo);

    pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    edit = pref.edit();

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(getBaseContext().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    this.registerReceiver(this.batteryInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

    txt_start_time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_start_time);
    txt_total_time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_total_time);
    txt_total_distance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_total_distance);
    txt_address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_address);

    try {
        TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);


        Editor edit = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                        getApplicationContext()).edit();
        edit.putString(IMEII, mTelephonyMgr.getDeviceId());
        edit.commit();
        Log.i(TAG, "IMEI Stored Sucessfully : "
                + PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString(IMEII, ""));
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Exception While Storin Data : " + e);
    }

   //       turnGPSOn(this);
   //   turnGPSOn();


    if(!isInternetOn()) {
        try {
        Method method = connectivityManager.getClass().getMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", boolean.class);
        method.invoke(connectivityManager, true);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
    hide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_hide);

    try {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        if(pref.getString(WORKING_STATUS, "").equals("NO")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(GPSDemo.this, NetworkTrackerService.class);

            startService(intent);
            edit.putString(WORKING_STATUS, "YES");
            edit.putString(START_TIME, sdf.format(new Date()));
            edit.commit();
            txt_start_time.setText(sdf.format(new Date()));
        } else if(pref.getString(WORKING_STATUS, "").equals("YES")) {
            txt_start_time.setText(pref.getString(START_TIME, ""));
        }
        updateInof();
        startInfoUpdater();
        Log.i("Abhi's Log", "Values Stored :: " +pref.getString(WORKING_STATUS, "") +" " + pref.getString(START_TIME, "") );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(GPSDemo.this, NetworkTrackerService.class);
            edit.putString(WORKING_STATUS, "NO");
            edit.putString(START_TIME, "");
            edit.putString(ADDRESS, "");
            edit.commit();
            stopService(intent);

            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    hide.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            GPSDemo.this.finish();
        }
    });



}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public  void turnGPSOn(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
    intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);

    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if (! provider.contains("gps"))
    { //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.tracking.gps", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        context.sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}

public void turnGPSOn()
{
     Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
     intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
     this.ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);

    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if(!provider.contains("gps"))
        { 
        //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        this.ctx.sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void turnGPSOff(Context context)
{
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if (provider.contains("gps"))
    { //if gps is enabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        context.sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
private void startInfoUpdater() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        //Do something after 100ms

          Log.v("Abhi's Tag", "Inside Schedulat ... !!!");

         updateInof();


          startInfoUpdater();
      }
    }, 60000);
}
protected void updateInof() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     long diffSeconds, diffMinutes = 0, diffHours = 0, diffDays = 0;

      SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
      currentTime = sdf1.format(new Date());

      try {
          d1 = sdf1.parse(pref.getString(START_TIME, ""));
          d2 = sdf1.parse(currentTime);

          long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

            diffSeconds = diff / (1000);
            diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
            diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
            diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

            Log.i("Abhi's Tag", "Days : " + diffDays);
            Log.i("Abhi's Tag", "Hours : " + diffHours);
            Log.i("Abhi's Tag", "Minutes : " + diffMinutes);
            Log.i("Abhi's Tag", "Seconds : " + diffSeconds);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


      txt_start_time.setText(pref.getString(START_TIME, ""));
      txt_total_time.setText(diffDays+" D, " + diffHours + " H, " + diffMinutes + " M");
      txt_address.setText(pref.getString(ADDRESS, ""));
}
private BroadcastReceiver batteryInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         level= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,0);

        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        Editor edit = pref.edit();
        edit.putInt("batteryStatus", level);
        edit.commit();


    }
};

public final boolean isInternetOn() {

    ConnectivityManager connec =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(getBaseContext().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if ( connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
             connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
             connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
             connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ) {

            return true;

        } else if ( connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ||  
                connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED  ) {

            return false;
        }
      return false;
    }
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

and I am getting this error

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this

```
 sdf1.parse(pref.getString(START_TIME, ""));
```

If the default value is returned its a empty string. So its natural you get `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:""`. You are parsing empty string

```
public abstract String getString (String key, String defValue)

Added in API level 1
Retrieve a String value from the preferences.

Returns the preference value if it exists, or defValue
```

Comment: @R.T. if the preference value for `START_TIME` exists you get the string. If not you get `""` by default. Its a empty string and you are parsing the empty as `sdf1.parse("");` which why you get the exception

Comment: sir i am getting prefernce value like thi android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl@42578b70

Comment: @R.T. that does not look a valid string. clearly `""` indicate empty string. read the stacktrace

Comment: @R.T. change to `sdf1.parse(pref.getString(START_TIME, "14/04/2014 14:27:13"))` for testing and check

Comment: @R.T. now what happens??

Comment: yes sir...,now its showing me date,..,but its for simple one date..,for dynamic value what i do???

Comment: @R.T. this means that preferences din't return the string. its returned the default date your provided. So you need to check that. You can show by default current date if you want

Comment: ok sir..,but i am using this functionality in daily updation..,so for that..what i do...,i want that every day .new date shown.

Comment: @R.T. what did you get by reading my previous comments. Re-read them again. A different problem post a different question. I don't want to comment long. What to do is for you to think. If this answer helps accept and post a different one